# MAUI change Control.Parent

Tags: controls, game-physics, parent, maui

iam going to swap my Gameboard game into MAUI and
stuck by change the parent of a control in .Net MAUI (Programmatically).

Following code doesnt give me any response and do nothing:

```
playerOne.Parent = FOne;
```

player1 is part of a Frame with the x:name=FZero and i want to display it into "FOne" (another Frame).

There a picture from current blank UI.
Player 1 should move to Field 1.

How to solve this.?

In Windows.Forms it is easy like that: Control.Parent = X; - done

[image]

Comment: what is `FOne`?

Comment: its another Frame

Comment: a `Frame` can only have a single child.  You can assign it using the `Content` property

Comment: FZero is also a Frame and contains 10 childs. or am i wrong?

Comment: Yes.  If you want multiple elements in a Frame you have to use a layout container like a stack or grid

Comment: Do you have a sample code which i should run programmatically after i declared the Grid Layout. I already have a Grid Layout in all Fields which contains 8 Frames (foreach player = 1 frame). So i already thought that i wanna need this, but i cant figure out how to change the position from FZero to FOne (F1P1). So in FOne there exists 8 Frames: named F1P1, F1P2 etc.

Comment: Use the Grid’s Children property to add/remove child elements.  If you need further help please post the relevant XAML/C# that demonstrates what you are trying to do

Comment: thanks. you helped me already a lot. i figured out that i have to Remove the child before. Everything is now working like expected. :) Win-Forms does make this automatically. Wasnt easy to realize about, that sometimes WinForms thought to much for me.

Comment: Any idea how to get the parent by using Reflection?   i thougt something like that      var T1 = player1.Parent.GetType().GetProperty("Id"); but this have no effect

Comment: ID is not a property of the object, it is just used by XAML to generate the variable name for C#.  If you want to identify an object at runtime you need to repurpose some other property, or otherwise keep track of your objects in code

Comment: thanks your awesome. you have great background knowledge :)